# Where is the PCV valve on my engine, and how can I check/change it?

Tags: chevrolet, suburban, pcv-valve

I have a Chevrolet suburban 2008 1500 with a 5.8L V8 engine. Can you describe with pictures where the PCV valve is, and how to check and replace it? I suspect it to have failed. Some have said it’s on the back of the left valve cover facing the front of the car (I.e. The corner closest to the passenger seat), but there is nothing there. Does this engine not have a PCV system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be located in the **driver's side (left)** valve cover towards the rear, pointing just about straight up. There should be a hose which is attached to it and plumbed into the intake manifold (IIRC). Whatever you're looking at (I really can't tell) does not look like the PCV at all.

Here's an image of the driver side valve cover (from RockAuto.com). If you were looking over the fender on the **driver's side**, this is what you'd see (with a bunch of coils and wires on top):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the wrong side of the engine, lol. I have found it now.

Comment: Any information on how to check it?

Comment: @TheLabCat - [This might help.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/15281/4152)_

Comment: Thanks. Anyways, why would advance auto parts be selling the PCV valve separate from the valve cover? It looks like the two can’t be separated, but… https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/carquest-premium-pcv-valve-pca1463/12578197-P?navigationPath=L1*81544%7CL2*82022%7CL3*-49998050

Comment: @TheLabCat - Because it can be separated? It's designed to be replaced.

Comment: I tried to get it out, but it’s not budging. It looks like they glued in with something yellow, and all the tutorials and information I can find say this model has it stuck permanently to the valve cover. Would be great though, as the valve cover with the PCV valve costs $175.

Comment: My guess? You just haven't tried hard enough :o) You may want to approach it as "Kill this one and replace it regardless".

Comment: I tried hard enough that I was tearing into the metal, and when I finally gave it up and just sprayed carburetor cleaner into the thing, I was concerned that the pointy scar edges would tear the PCV hose.